# PDF thumbnail generation for Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an Android app that manages PDFs. I know that **Cloudinary** allows users to upload PDFs and automatically generate thumbnails for the uploaded PDF (see [here](https://cloudinary.com/blog/uploading_converting_and_generating_thumbnails_for_pdf_documents)). Does **Firebase Storage** or **Cloud Firestore** offer a similar feature? If not, any recommended third-party tool for this task? Thanks!

Comment: You should take a look here: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/generate-thumbnail

Comment: @DauleDK: Thanks, but this is for images. i am looking for a PDF thumbnail generator.

Comment: Without knowing a lot about thumbnail PDF generations, can you maybe look at this module? https://github.com/mooz/node-pdf-image? The point is that the combination of firebase functions and storage is very powerfull  :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Intro

ImageMagick comes pre installed on the cloud function environment, but Ghostscript does not (at least, not right now). Ghostscript is what’s needed to generate images from PDFs.

First, download a copy of the Ghostscript executable from [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) (linux 64 bit APGL Release), and store it in the root of your functions directory. You may want to rename the folder/executable name for shorter path references. This will be deployed when you deploy your function(s).

Second as seen in [this repo](https://github.com/sina-masnadi/node-gs), `npm install —-save https://github.com/sina-masnadi/node-gs/tarball/master` . This is a wrapper you’ll need to communicate with the Ghostscript executable from within your function.

Third, you may want to look over the [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm) / [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php) docs to customize even further.

### Sample cloud function

Finally, here is a function that I just got working for **my** functions file structure. You’ll need to write better validation and tweek it for your setup, but know that the meat of this will work.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const fs = require('fs');
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');
const write = require('fs-writefile-promise');
const spawn = require('child-process-promise').spawn;
const mkdirp = require('mkdirp-promise');
const gs = require('gs');
const gs_exec_path = path.join(__dirname, '../../../ghostscript/./gs-923-linux-x86_64');

try { admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase); } catch(e) {}


/*
  Callable https function that takes a base 64 string of a pdf (MAX 
  10mb), uploads a thumbnail of it to firebase storage, and returns its 
  download url.
 */
module.exports = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  if (!data.b64str) { throw Error('missing base 64 string of pdf!'); }

  const b64pdf = data.b64str.split(';base64,').pop();
  const pg = typeof data.pg === 'number' ? data.pg : 1; //1-based
  const max_wd = typeof data.max_wd === 'number' ? data.max_wd : 200;
  const max_ht = typeof data.max_ht === 'number' ? data.max_ht : 200;
  const st_fname = typeof data.fname === 'string' ? data.fname : 'whatever.jpg';

  const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
  const tmp_dir = os.tmpdir();
  const tmp_pdf = path.join(tmp_dir, 'tmp.pdf');
  const tmp_png = path.join(tmp_dir, 'doesntmatter.png');
  const tmp_thumb = path.join(tmp_dir, st_fname.split('/').pop();
  const st_thumb = st_fname;

  /* create tmp directory to write tmp files to... */
  return mkdirp(tmp_dir).then(() => {
    /* create a temp pdf of the base 64 pdf */
    return write(tmp_pdf, b64pdf, {encoding:'base64'});
  }).then(() => {
    /* let ghostscript make a png of a page in the pdf */
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      gs().batch().nopause()
          .option(`-dFirstPage=${pg}`)
          .option(`-dLastPage=${pg}`)
          .executablePath(gs_exec_path)
          .device('png16m')
          .output(tmp_png)
          .input(tmp_pdf)
          .exec(err => err ? reject(err) : resolve());
    });
  }).then(() => {
    /* make a thumbnail for the png generated by ghostscript via imagemagick */
    var args = [ tmp_png, '-thumbnail', `${max_wd}x${max_ht}>`, tmp_thumb ];
    return spawn('convert', args, {capture: ['stdout', 'stderr']});
  }).then(() => {
    /* upload tmp_thumb to storage. */
    return bucket.upload(tmp_thumb, { destination: st_thumb });
  }).then(() => {
    /* get storage url for the uploaded thumbnail */
    return bucket.file(st_thumb).getSignedUrl({
      action:'read',
      expires: '03-01-2500'
    });
  }).then(result => {
    /* clean up temp files and respond w/ download url */
    fs.unlinkSync(tmp_pdf);
    fs.unlinkSync(tmp_png);
    fs.unlinkSync(tmp_thumb);
    return result[0];
  });
});
```

### Sample invocation from client

```
var fn = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('https_fn_name');

fn({
  b64str: 'base64 string for pdf here....',
  pg: 2, //optional, which page do u want a thumbnail of? 1 is the first.
  fname: 'path/to/file/in/storage.jpg', //optional but recommended, .png if u like
  max_wd: 300, // optional, max thumbnail width
  max_ht: 300  // optional, max thumbnail height
}).then(res => console.log(res));
```

### If you cant generate a signed url...

You'll need to **Add** the role "Cloud Functions Service Agent" to whatever service account this function is using. You can **Add** the role to your service account in your [cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam).

[image: How to add the role]

Comment: Thank @Vincent You saved my day !!! More Explanation or to use jpeg format 
follow link[ https://tech.residebrokerage.com/using-firebase-cloud-functions-with-ghostscript-for-pdf-to-image-conversion-f81b248d3b22 ]